# How create Path on a Live server in C# code?

Tags: c#

The below code shows how I created a `Path/Directory` to Local Machine. Now, I want to put my Application to the Live server but my problem it creates a File to a given Path on a Live server, how can I achieve it?

```
`string appPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
 string IPAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

 Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath + "//PrintFiles/" + IPAddress");
 StreamWriter w;

 w = File.CreateText(appPath + "//PrintLabels/" + IPAddress + "/printLabels.txt");
 w.WriteLine(fileContents.ToString());
 w.Flush();
 w.Close();`
```

Comment: Most likely permission issues.

Comment: `How to create path on live server` okay.... `my problem it does create a File to a given Path on a Live server` now I'm confused

Comment: The question is unclear; can you please rephrase?

Comment: @Shawn thanks a lot ,permissions problem ,sorted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same code will work if the server has access to the target location. But the process running the code has to have rights which will allow for directory creation at the target location. If it is a local process to a non local resource, then the process needs either needs to be known to both computers or a system wide process should kick off the code.

For example if this process is in IIS, then the app pool user needs to be set to a process which has access rights to the target location.